# Программирование на языке C с использованием командной строки

Tags: c, cmd

Для сдачи калькулятора в лабораторной работе по языку Си нужно использовать командную строку, аргументы в методе main, без использования объектов. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно взять информацию о работе с командной строкой для программирования на языке Си?

Comment: Может быть имеется в виду просто консольное приложение, без GUI?

Comment: запуск компиляции зависит от компилятора (странно да?). Если Borland C, это bcc, GNU Compiler Collection  - gcc. В visual, кажется cl

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете к примеру установить **"C-Program Compiler (gcc)"** компилятор кода на языке С.

После этого с помощью блокнота либо notepad++ либо любого другого редактора написать сам код, и сохранить, используя расширение **.с** в конце имени файла. Далее открыть командную строку, перейти к папке где лежит файл с кодом вашего калькулятора и запустить используя команду:

*gcc названиеВашегоФайла.с*

На этом все.